# Display a 2d array of buttons in android

Tags: android, arrays, button, multidimensional-array

I made a subclass of button called Block for a minesweeper like game. I then made a 2d array of this class. Is there an easy way to display this array in a grid?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should use a `GridView` with a custom adapter. There is enough documentation available at 
[the Android developer website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

Here is a [tutorial for a custom adapter](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-baseadapter/). The tutorial uses a `ListView`, but the adapter will also work with a `GridView`